# install rmagick gem on ubuntu 14.04 vagrant VM

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, vagrant, rmagick

I have problem to install rmagick gem to vagrant VM.

`sudo apt-get update` done!

I've installed to vagrant this:

- imagemagick
- libmagickwand-dev
- graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
- libmagickcore-dev
- libmagickwand5

And error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.4/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

What I forgot?

Comment: after ```vagrant destroy``` and ```vagrant up``` problem was solved.

Comment: If that fix your problem, you can answer it by yourself. If this can fix, then running `vagrant reload --provision` should fix this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this, and problem was solved.

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand5 libmagickwand-dev  
gem install rmagick -v 2.13.3
```